# How to pass a state of one class to another without navigation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget class called landing page and I have made a new class on scaffold body, but how do I pass the state of landing page to the landing page body class

I found methods for passing the data by navigation only .

```
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
    bool notificationTap = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(......),
        body: LandingPageBody(),
      );
  }
}
```

Here I want to pass _notificationTap state of LandingPage to LandingPageBody class

Answer (score 1):

Through the constructor...

```
body: LandingPageBody(notificationTap),
```

```
class LandingPageBody extends StatefulWidget {

   final bool notificationTap;

   LandingPageBody(this.notificationTap);

   @override
   createState() => _LandingPageBodyState();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. I should make constructor on my LandingPageBody

Comment: yeah sorry.. mark as correct answer if you fixed it